# Determinant of exterior power

Tags: linear-algebra, determinants, multilinear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a $n$ times $n$ matrix.

What is the determinant of the $i$-th exterior power of $A$, in terms of determinant of $A$?

Answer (score 21):

The answer is just $\det(\Lambda^i(A))=\det(A)^m$, where $m=\binom{n-1}{i-1}$.  Indeed, by continuity it is enough to prove this when $A$ is diagonalisable, and by conjugation-invariance it suffices to prove it when $A$ is diagonal, and in that case it is straightforward.  Alternatively, you can show that $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the commutator subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ and thus that any polynomial homomorphism $GL_n(\mathbb{C})\to\mathbb{C}^\times$ is a power of the determinant.  To find the relevant power, just take $A$ to be a multiple of the identity.

Comment: This result is called the Sylvester--Franke theorem.

Comment: Neil's first argument works over an arbitrary field: first observe that WLOG the field is alg closed, and then use the Zariski topology for the continuity argument.

Comment: In that case I'd say the result is true over any commutative ring, since the formula can be regarded as a universal polynomial identity over Z and thus it suffices to check it over the complex numbers.