# A polynomial homomorphism from Gl to the group of units is a power of the determinant

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, algebraic-groups

I was browsing MO and stumbled upon [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70889/determinant-of-exterior-power), and I got very curious. I searched for about half an hour and could not find a proof for the statement that any polynomial group homomorphism $\mathrm{Gl}_n(\Bbbk)\to\Bbbk^\times$ is a power of the determinant. Now this is certainly classic, so could someone point me to a good reference? I would prefer a proof that can be presented to graduate students with a mild background in classical algebraic geometry.

**Edit:** I was also wondering about the following: If $G$ is an affine algebraic group (i.e. an affine $\Bbbk$-variety with compatible group structure), then there is a closed immersion of $\iota:G\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Gl}_n(\Bbbk)$. From such an immersion, I get a "determinant" on $G$, namely $\iota^\sharp(\det)$. Is this, by any chance, independent of the embedding up to taking powers?

Comment: No.
You can modify the resulting "determinant" by any character $\chi:G\to \text{GL}_1(\bf k)$, simply by enlarging $n$ by one and using the extra entry on the diagonal as target for $\chi$. 

Comment: Your argument seems to be kindof circular - the group homomorphisms $G\to\Bbbk^\times$ **are** the characters, and if all of them are powers of a determinant, then so is the modification you propose, because the extra entry on the diagonal will mean multiplication with some power of the determinant. 

Comment: @Jesko -- As I believe others point out below, van der Kallen's argument is completely correct and certainly is not circular.  If you take an algebraic group like $\mathbf{G}_m\times \mathbf{G}_m$, a product of two copies of the multiplicative group, then the group of characters has rank $>1$, i.e., it is not the case that all characters are related to, i.e., commensurate with, a single "determinant" character.  Thus if you modify your linear representation as van der Kallen suggests by these characters, the associated determinants will also be non-commensurate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since ${\mathbb k}^\times$ is abelian, any group hom $\phi : GL_n ({\mathbb k}) \rightarrow{\mathbb k}^\times$ factors through $\phi : GL_n ({\mathbb k}) \rightarrow GL_n({\mathbb k})/[GL_n({\mathbb k}),GL_n({\mathbb k})]  \rightarrow{\mathbb k}^\times$. It is a nice easy exercise that $[GL_n({\mathbb k}),GL_n({\mathbb k})] = SL_n({\mathbb k})$. Thus, the factorization turns out to be $\phi : GL_n ({\mathbb k}) \xrightarrow{\det} {\mathbb k}^\times  \rightarrow{\mathbb k}^\times$.

If you want your hom to be polynomial the corresponding endomorphism of the multiplicative group ought to be polynomial. Notice that I am not making any assumptions about the field...

Comment: That is, indeed, very nice and brief. Do you have any ideas about my edit?

Comment: Off course, it is not independent. Take $G$ to be the Klein-4-group. It will have 3 diagonal immersions into $GL(2)$, each immersion different elements will have determinant 1.

Comment: I don't fully understand: What exactly are these diagonal immersions? What do you mean by your last statement?

Comment: Technical note: $SL_n(k) = [GL_n(k), GL_n(k)]$ in all cases EXCEPT $n=2$ and $k=\mathbb{F}_2$ or $\mathbb{F}_3$. Doesn't effect the end result, because you could always extend the base field before running your argument. See Lang's <i>Algebra</i>, Chapter XIII.

Comment: Why could I always extend the base field without the map losing its homomorphism property?

Comment: (I am aware that the less naive and closer-to-the-substance avatar of the question is about homomorphisms of *algebraic* groups rather than homomorphisms of abstract groups which happen to be polynomial maps; thus this question is somewhat tongue-in-cheek.)

Comment: Elaborating on Bugs Bunny's Klein-4 suggestion: the group $\{\pm1\}\times\{\pm1\}$ has three nontrivial 1-dim'l representations: $\{(-1,1)\mapsto 1, (1,-1)\mapsto -1\}$, $\{(-1,1)\mapsto -1, (1,-1)\mapsto 1\}$, $\{(-1,1)\mapsto -1, (1,-1)\mapsto -1\}$. In general, finite abelian groups have a lot of embeddings into $GL_1$...

Comment: David, except $n=2$ and $k=F_2$ only, which is a very special case as $k^\times$ is trivial:-)) So you dont need any extensions. If $k=F_3$, $SL_2$ is not perfect but still the commutant of $GL_2$

Comment: Vladimir, your "embeddings" have kernels :-))


Comment: Jesko, Vladimir virtually answered your question: you have 4 2x2-matrices with $\pm 1$ on the diagonal. But there are 3 different embeddings of $K_4$ with this image...

Comment: Maybe I am just being silly, but it is not clear to me that the resulting map $k^{\times} \to k^{\times}$ will be algebraic. 

Comment: Bugs Bunny: yes, you're right, I was typing it preoccupied with something else, and ended up saying something silly. All necessary information was there though :)

Comment: QY, just apply the original map to the diagonal matrix $Diag(x,1,1,1...)$

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell if you want a reference to a proof or just a proof, but here's a proof.

By multiplying by a suitable power of the determinant we may assume that such a homomorphism extends to a polynomial monoid homomorphism $\mathcal{M}_n(k) \to k$, and since it is polynomial it extends to a homomorphism $\phi : \mathcal{M}_n(\bar{k}) \to \bar{k}$. Since $\bar{k}$ is abelian, $\phi$ is conjugation-invariant. Restricted to diagonal matrices $\phi$ must be a symmetric polynomial in their diagonal entries, and since the diagonalizable matrices are Zariski dense in $\mathcal{M}_n(\bar{k})$, $\phi$ must be a symmetric polynomial in the eigenvalues (hence a polynomial in the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial) identically. By scaling entries of elements of $\mathcal{M}_n(\bar{k})$, $\phi$ must be a homogeneous polynomial.

Assume WLOG that $\phi$ is not divisible by the determinant. If $\phi$ has degree $0$ as a homogeneous polynomial, then it must be the trivial homomorphism. Otherwise, $\phi$ is a homogeneous polynomial of positive degree, so in particular $\phi(0) = 0$. Now, if $D_1$ is a diagonal matrix with a zero entry, then we can find conjugates $D_2, ... D_n$ of $D_1$ which are also diagonal but with the zero entry at every possible other location. It follows that $D_1 ... D_n = 0$, so $\phi(D_1 ... D_n) = \phi(D_1)^n = 0$, so $\phi(D_1) = 0$. Hence $\phi(M)$ vanishes if any of the eigenvalues of $M$ vanish, so $\phi$ is divisible by the determinant; contradiction.

**Edit:** Your proposed extension is false. Take $G = \text{GL}_1 \times \text{GL}_1$ and embed using different powers for each factor...

Answer (score 3):

A simple proof in case that $\mathbb{K}$ is infinite can be found in my answer here:

[determinants and polynomials in matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98997/determinants-and-polynomials-in-matrices/99056#99056)

It is based on the fact that $SL_n(\mathbb{K})$ is perfect. This is just Theorem 14.8 in [this paper](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math101b/SL.pdf). The proof is short and elementary.

Comment: I think it is even simpler than that. I will have a go...

Answer (score 1):

As people have pointed out, the question raised in the Edit has a negative answer.   To clarify this, start with $G = \mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ (for an algebraically closed field $K$) and embed $G$ (or any closed subgroup) into $\mathrm{GL}_{n+1}(K)$ as block diagonal matrices $(A, 1/\det A)$ with zero entries elsewhere.   In this way $G$ actually embeds in the special linear group, so applying $\det$ gives the trivial map on the embedded copy of $G$.

This is just a variant of the standard procedure used to see that $G$ (which at first looks like a Zariski-open subset of affine $n^2$-space) can in fact be viewed concretely as the zero set of some polynomials in an affine space of dimension $n^2+1$.